# How do I hide the embedded swf's file name?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, security, flash, embed

I'm writing a simple game in Flash CS3 ActionScript, and I embed the swf output to my website. But, for now, the .swf file is directly downloadable. And it contains things that the players should not see, like the "AJAX" calls.

So I'm wondering, if one can see the source code from my swf?

And if so, how can I embed the swf in a way that the user does not see the filename?
Instead of `<embed src='./myswf.swf'></embed>` ?

- So the real question becomes, how do I hide the swf's filename?

Comment: An alternate might be to obfuscate the swf.  It's hard to say how much it'd help, though.

Answer (score 0):

SWF files can be decompiled. You can obfuscate the code but it still can be decompiled and anyone can extract any resource they want.

In your case, I suspect they won't even need to decompile since what you want to hide are the AJAX calls. These however can be viewed directly in any browser developer tool or proxy.

Comment: You are probably right. The as3 code contains things like 'var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);' where url is something like 'http://mysite/ajax_agent.php?action=insert_data&etc=etc'